# redux-form change list of dropdown options from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am not seeing the solution to this issue which I am sure is obvious. Classic country/state issue
scenario:
redux form with two Form.Select (semantic ui-react) Fields

```
 <FormSection name="addressInfo">  
          <Field
            component={renderSelect}
            label="Country"
            fieldName="country"
            name="country"
            onChange={(newValue) =>
              change("addressInfo.provState", renderProvinceState(newValue))
            }
            options={renderCountries()}
          />
          <Field
            component={renderSelect}
            label="Province/State"
            fieldName="provState"
            name="provState"
            multiple
            options={renderProvinceState("Canada")}
          />
```

my option builders are the following:

```
  const renderCountries = () => {
    
    if (!countries) return null;
    var options = [];
    Object.keys(countries).map((key) => {
      options.push({
        key: key,
        text: countries[key].country,
        value: countries[key].country,
      });
      return null;
    });
    return options;
  };

  const renderProvinceState = (country) => {
    if (!country) return null;
    var states = countries.filter((s) => s.country == country)[0].states;

    if (!states) return null;
    var options = [];
    Object.keys(states).map((key) => {
      options.push({
        key: key,
        text: states[key],
        value: states[key],
      });
      return null;
    });
    return options;
  };
```

my dropdowns create successfully, I get a list of countries and provinces for canada. When I change the country I get the following errors:

```
index.js:1 Dropdown `value` must not be an array when `multiple` is not set. Either set `multiple={true}` or use a string or number value.
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Dropdown`.
```

I am new to react, react-redux and would appreciate any insight someone might have. I have tried adding value={[]} to the provState obj but that didn't fix anything.

the actual component I am working with looks like this:

```
export const renderSelect = ({
  label,
  meta,
  input,
  name,
  options,
  placeholder,
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Select
      className={`${meta.error && meta.touched ? "error" : ""}`}
      label={label}
      name={input.name}
      onChange={(e, { value }) => input.onChange(value)}
      options={options}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={input.value}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: where is this change("addressInfo.provState", renderProvinceState(newValue)) function define d?

Comment: change is coming form the Redux-form OnChange event.
```
  <RegistrationSecondPage
            onChange={onChange}
            countries={this.props.countries}
            provState={this.props.provinceState}
```

Comment: this is definitely my issue 
 onChange={(newValue) =>
              change("addressInfo.provState", renderProvinceState(newValue))
            }
but I can't see how to fix it. the change() is completely wrong as it wires back to a completely different function